# PDF gerado do HTML, através do itext (5.5.6), não tem o tamanho da fonte definida no CSS

Tags: java, itext

Estou usando o itext 5.5.6 para gerar um arquivo PDF a partir de um documento HTML gerado pelo thymeleaf.

Neste HTML, os estilos estão sendo refletidos corretamente no browser. Porém, ao gerar o PDF, este apresenta todos os estilos corretamente, exceto a definição de "font-size".

Alguém poderia ajudar?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        FileInputStream cssFis =
                new FileInputStream("estilo.css");

        ...

        String resultado = ... // String contendo o HTML

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(resultado.getBytes());

        // itextpdf e itext tools

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("arquivo.pdf"));

        document.open();

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(cssFis);
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(bais);

        document.close();

    }
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
.tabela {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.cabecalho {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.linha_numero {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Cadastros Veiculo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tabela" class="tabela">
        <tr class="cabecalho">
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">ID</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">PLACA</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">PROPRIETARIO</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">CPF</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">RENAVAM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0</td>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">X</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">X</td>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0</td>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Teria como gerar um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para reproduzir o problema? Só com isto fica um pouco difícil ajudar.

Comment: Atualizei conforme a pergunta feita no stackoverflow em inglês. Obrigado.